# Semigroups on Banach lattice

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators, banach-lattices

Let $\{Z(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ be a semigroup of positive operators on a Banach lattice $X$. I want to show that

$$\int_0^1[Z(1-s)+Z(1+s)]fds-f\in X_+,\quad f\in X_+$$

Where $X_+$ denotes the positive part of $X$.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? Why do you want to show that? Do you have a reason to believe that it's true? Is it homework, research or something else?

Comment: Try $X$ as the (uniformly) continuous bounded functions on $\mathbb R$, the translation group $Z(t)(f)(x)=f(x+t)$ and a positive function $f$ with $f(0)=1$ which decays rapidly (e.g. $f(x)=\exp(-|x|)$).

Comment: On the first sight the previous example of @JochenWengenroth can be made one-dimensional by taking $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $Z(t)=e^{-t}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for these meaningful suggestions but I don't want to be particular. it is a part of my research problem and I want such results for some general space ordered space. since $Z(t)$ are positive operators I do feel it must be satisfied.

Comment: But the examples suggest that this cannot be true...